# Why celery doesn't send tasks to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery with Django and RabbitMQ. When I do

```
task.delay()
```

I get an AsyncResult, but the task never gets to celery workers and when I check

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

I see that my queue has 0 messages. When I delete the queue and do "task.delay()" again, the queue is recreated, but it is still empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spent just too many time yesterday resolving this issue.

Turns out the problem is disk space: by default when free disk space goes below 1GB, RabbitMQ starts silently dropping messages.

In fact you can see a message about it in RabbitMQ startup logs, but if it was running for a while you may have trouble finding it.

To resolve the problem you can just clear enough disk space or modify the [disk_free_limit RabbitMQ setting](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).